# Is there an API to extract questions and labels from yahoo answers?

Tags: machine-learning, data, naive-bayes-classifier

I want to work on a ML project which involves the family and relationship category from yahoo answers. I want to extract questions from yahoo answers (only the title) with the label as the category it is in on yahoo answers. I want to use it in csv form to train my naive bayes model. Is there an API or something similar to do so ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems as though there is a lot of advice on the [Yahoo Developer Site](https://developer.yahoo.com/faq/?guccounter=1).

Basic steps will be:

1. get yourself a standard Yahoo account
2. using that account, get yourself an *Application ID* (basically an API key)
3. (probably) get a unique password to go with your API key

This will all allow you to authenticate yourself when making requests for data.

There are daily rate limits for data requests, they say:

> Each service may have different limits on the number of results returned by each query, as well as other variations in supported parameters. The documentation for each service specifies the default number and maximum number you can receive.

I should also point out that the service is not intended for commercial use, so if you plan to make a product and sell it, based on Yahoo data, you need to probably discuss the API usage with them.

---

The results will be in a form that requires parsing, such as XML, as it seems to be a standard web requests API. This means you can look at tools such as [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) or the xml [ElementTree](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). You can then choose the specific parts of the received data from Yahoo's API.